# Deserialize <table> nodes to double[][] from XML

Tags: c#, .net, multidimensional-array, deserialization, xml-namespaces

I have an XML file (from somewhere) containing matrix values, which I wish to get into my code as double[][] objects. The XML contains table nodes, which look like standard serialized double[][] objects:

```
<table type="System.Double[][]"><table type="System.Double[]"><el type="System.Double">0.005</el><el type="System.Double">0.001</el><el type="System.Double">0.007</el><el type="System.Double">-0.012</el></table><table type="System.Double[]"><el type="System.Double">0.033</el><el type="System.Double">-0.146</el><el type="System.Double">-0.008</el><el type="System.Double">0.006</el></table><table type="System.Double[]"><el type="System.Double">-0.002</el><el type="System.Double">-0.004</el><el type="System.Double">-0.004</el><el type="System.Double">-0.003</el></table><table type="System.Double[]"><el type="System.Double">0</el><el type="System.Double">0</el><el type="System.Double">0</el><el type="System.Double">0</el></table></table>
```

Since not the whole XML is in this form, I only extract those nodes as XmlNode (since XElements don't have InnerXml). Lets call this `myMatrixXmlNode`.
Then, I try to put that into a MemoryStream, and then deserialize from that:

```
var deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(double[][]));
var myMatrix = (double[][])deserializer.Deserialize(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myMatrixXmlNode.InnerXml)));
```

This throws me a `<table xmlns=''> was not expected.` error, for which I have not found a solution yet.. and I'm geting really annoyed by this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use standart Xml serializer for deserializing this Xml into `double[][]`.

Format for `double[][]` Xml serialization is like:

```xml
<ArrayOfArrayOfDouble xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'     xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>
  <ArrayOfDouble>
    <double>1</double>
  </ArrayOfDouble>
  <ArrayOfDouble>
    <double>2</double>
  </ArrayOfDouble>
</ArrayOfArrayOfDouble>
```

You can try parse thos Xml manually using LinqToXml or transforming it to corresponding format.

Answer (score 2):

Probably best to use an XDocument to parse it like the following:-

```
    var d = XDocument.Parse(testXml);
    var r = d.Element("table");

    var listOfDoubleArrays = new List<double[]>();
    foreach (var outerArrayItem in r.Elements())
    {
        double[] arr = new double[r.Elements().Count()];
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var innerArrayItem in outerArrayItem.Elements())
        {
            arr[i] = System.Convert.ToDouble(innerArrayItem.Value);
            i++;
        }
        listOfDoubleArrays.Add(arr);
    }
    double[][] result = listOfDoubleArrays.ToArray();
```